# Error Starting function after if statement using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Haven't really create my own function before, so what I am attempting is to start the scripts below the line `function NewsUpdate`, but I want them to be apart of the function. In the if statement, when the script finds the string "News Update" in the 'email message' it will start those scripts, if not (the else statement all the way at the bottom) it will fail and say "News Update not found in e-mail message"

But I get the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION

What am I doing wrong?

```
// Test code for email message.
$open_email_msg =  file_get_contents('emailmessage.html');

// A script that searches the e-mail for the string News Update,
// and if it is found it will start the function NewsUpdate

if(strpos($open_email_msg,"News Update"))
    function NewsUpdate ($open_email_msg) {
        // Login to MySQL Datebase
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $db_user = "user";
        $db_password = "pass";
        $database = "tablename";
        $db_table = "bx_news_entries";
        $db = mysql_connect($hostname, $db_user, $db_password);
        mysql_select_db($database,$db);
        $subject = 'Test News Article';
        $tags = str_replace(' ',',',$subject); // DDIE
        $uri =  str_replace(' ','-',$subject); // DDIE
        $when = strtotime("now");    // date article was posted
        $categories = 'Events';
        $content = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.';
        $snippet = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';
        // $snippet = explode(".", $content, -1);
        # THIS CODE WILL TELL MYSQL TO INSERT THE DATA FROM THE EMAIL INTO YOUR MYSQL TABLE
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $db_table(`caption`, `snippet`, `content`, `when`, `uri`, `tags`, `categories`, `DATE`) values ('$subject', '$snippet', '$content', '$when', '$uri', '$tags', '$categories', '$when')";
        if($result = mysql_query($sql ,$db)) {
        } else {
            echo "ERROR: ".mysql_error();
        }
        echo "<h1>News Article added!</h1>";
    }

else {
    echo "<h3>'News Update</h3>not found in e-mail message!";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your function above and call it:

```
function NewsUpdate ($open_email_msg) {
    //function declaration
}

//Test code for email message.

$open_email_msg =  file_get_contents('emailmessage.html');

//A script that searches the e-mail for the string News Update, and if it is found it will start the function NewsUpdate

if(strpos($open_email_msg,"News Update"))
    NewsUpdate ($open_email_msg);
else {

    echo "<h3>'News Update</h3>not found in e-mail message!";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Real answer: Don't define functions conditionally like that. It makes for nasty unmaintainable code.

Bad answer:

```
        if(strpos($open_email_msg,"News Update")) {
                                                  ^---- missing bracket
            function NewsUpdate ($open_email_msg) {
```

As well, your strpos **CAN** blow up on you. strpos CAN return an integer `0` if the string you're searching for is at the start of the string, which will then be interpreted as a boolean false. Never EVER test strpos as you are, always have

```
if (strpos(...) === FALSE) {
```

which will properly catch the case where the 'needle' is not in the 'haystack', but still allow a 0-positioned needle.

Comment: no missing bracket. his `else` is fine:

`if /*blablabla*/ else { /*blablabla*/ }`

Comment: Even if you think it is bad practice, and there are way better ways of achieving this, consider the first time you learn about functions and you need dynamically defined ones, this would be your first implementation, and the question was about what he did wrong, except bad practices.

Comment: @silent: try it: `if (true) function x() { return 'x'; }`. it dies with a syntax error unless you have {} around the function definition itself.

Comment: @khael: this isn't a dynamic function. It's a conditionally defined one. dynamic functions would be `$x = function() { ... }`.

Comment: @MarcB, I see what you did there, sir. My point was related to my answer (moving the function outside the `if` statement) and I mistakenly relating your answer to it.

Comment: @MarcB Well, no, that would be an anonymous function, a dynamically created function is a function created under some specific conditions, but in the given code that would just won't matter as the function would anyway be parsed and created.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try adding some `{` after if statement. and one `}` after you a `;` at the end of the function definition.

You need at leats one valid instruction, or a block before you can add an `else` statement there.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is completely incorrect.  A function is a block of code that you can execute over an  over from different places in a script.  A function is not defined where it is used and cannot be defined inside an if block.  *Edit: as pointed out functions can be defined inside the main code block and even conditionally inside an if.  This is however a more advanced use and can get you into trouble if not used carefully.*  What you need to do is define your function somewhere outside of the main execution of your page and then call it in the if block.  For example:

```
<?php
//main execution
if (var == true) {
   $myVar = myFunction('Bob', 'blue'); //we are calling the function and passing the values 'Bob' and 'blue' to the variables in the function definition
   echo $myVar //this will print the returned value 'Yay'
}
//end of main execution

function myFunction($name, $color) {
  echo "Hi, " . $name . ", You like " . $color; //this uses the passed in values which are assigned to the variable names in the definition
  return 'Yay'; //we are returning a value of 'Yay' to the calling code
}

?>
```

Basically the function definition is separate from the main execution of the script, and the code inside of the function will only be run if the function is called using myFunction();  This can be called as many times as you like during execution.  Also you can send parameters to a function by definition (like the name and color I'm passing in the example) and the function can return information back to the code calling it as I have shown.  Note, it is common practice to define all functions either at the end or beginning of a file, but you don't have to.

Comment: function can be defined inside if: `if(true)
{
   function call_it( $c){
       echo $c;
   }
}
`

Comment: Defining function inside if statements is common practice for ensuring backward compatibility: `if (!function_exists('json_encode')) { function json_encode() { ...} }`

Comment: You are correct, though for someone new to functions I felt it simpler not to go down this road. I have updated my answer, along with a note of caution.

Comment: thanks for the answer i'll definitely implore this method in my future endeavors in PHP as well.